# Axios Error Networ error on request Google place api

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, google-places-api

im trying to make a request to google api but returns me network error. If i put the url in the browser, brings me the information correctly.I tryed to formate the request without success. The google places search works correctly too.

```
export const fetch_information = (skip, limit, filter) => async (dispatch) => {

    try {

    var url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJk0aJYPbk3JQRLpKN20Jecko&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=MyKey`;


        const {data} = await axios.get(url)
        console.log(data)

    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error.message)


    }
}
```

and

```
export const fetch_information = (skip, limit, filter) => async (dispatch) => {

    try {


        var url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?`;
        let config = {
            params: {
                place_id: 'ChIJk0aJYPbk3JQRLpKN20Jecko',
                key: 'myKey',

            },
        }

        const {data} = await axios.get(url, config)
        console.log(data)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the request looks a bit messy. I'm under the impression that you are trying to pass results to a redux store. Let's see if we can clean this up a bit.

```
export const fetch_information = async () => dispatch => {

    const req = await axios.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJk0aJYPbk3JQRLpKN20Jecko&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=MyKey");
    const data = await req.json();

    return data;
    //or, for your purpose...
    console.log(data);
    //can also dispatch for store
}
```

I didn't see anything you were passing as necessary for this.

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me the same error @TimWilson , there is some block in the google api and i dont know what is.

Comment: Maybe a ridiculous question on my part but do you have that particular api enabled in the developer console?